# WPF - Making Checked and Unchecked event to execute before actually check or uncheck?

Tags: wpf

My problem is the fellowing. I have a ListView which is bind to a list of object. Then i have a property in that object that is a boolean. In the ListView i have a checkbox which is set to checked or unchecked depending of the value of the bool of that particuliar object in the list.

So i told myself, why not when you click it perform some action on that row.. but the problem is that the action can be cancelled by the user such showing a windows with both apply and cancel. In the event of the user cancel the action.. the checkbox get checked anyway!

Is there a way to cancel this action ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't have any special processing for when the checkbox is unchecked, then you can just move your special processing to occur when the checkbox is checked rather than firing on when it is clicked.  If the cancel is chosen then you can uncheck the checkbox again by resetting the source bool in your object to False, and ignore the unchecked event.

If you do have special processing for unchecked, you can use the binding's SourceUpdated event to detect when the checkbox caused the bool to flip to false rather than the bool causing the checkbox to flip to unchecked.

If you want to detect when your object's bool caused a check to update:

```
<CheckBox isChecked="{Binding MyBool, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" TargetUpdated="MyTargetUpdated"/>
```

If you want to detect when your checkbox caused your object's bool to update:

```
<CheckBox isChecked="{Binding MyBool, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" SourceUpdated="MySourceUpdated"/>
```

You can do both at the same time, thus detecting changes both ways and acting accordingly, so that you can choose to act only when the data updated or only when the CheckBox updated.

Comment: Any example for this part ? "you can use the binding's SourceUpdated event"

Answer (score 0):

I may be misinterpreting your question but it sounds like what you want is you have a ListView with a CheckBox bound to a property in a ViewModel.  When the CheckBox is checked or unchecked, you have an event that performs some cancelable action.  When the action is canceled, you want to restore the checkbox value to the value before the original check?

If this is so, in the cancel case, just not the IsChecked property in the code behind or not the property value in your ViewModel.

Comment: Most of your explanation is right. this part is wrong "When the CheckBox is checked or unchecked, you have an event that performs some cancelable action." That click on the checkbox performs an event where the user must be able to cancel that event. That why i show a dialog box with 2 buttons.

Comment: Instead of Click can you use PreviewMouseDown?  In there, set a property somewhere that informs of the cancel.  Then, in the Checked/Unchecked events revert the changes if that property is true.  This should work because the PreviewMouseDown event fires before the Checked/Unchecked events whereas the Click event fires afterward.

Comment: Using PreviewMouseDown would mean the check didn't appear in the checkbox before his dialog popped up.  This could confuse the user.

Comment: I'm assuming he needs the click event or else I agree with answer above.  I think the real issue is the idea is doesn't make sense.  Maybe instead of always having a checkbox you have an edit link.  Then show the checkbox once the settings are established.

Or instead of having a cancel, just have an apply.  If the user wants to cancel changes, they uncheck the checkbox.